# Write negated string according to POS tags

Tags: php, regex, nlp, regex-negation

Consider the following POS-tagged string:

```
It/PRP was/VBD not/RB okay/JJ or/CC funny/JJ and/CC I/NN will/MD never/RB buy/VB 
from/IN them/PRP ever/RB again/RB

(It was not okay or funny and I will never buy from them ever again)
```

I want to accomplish the following:

1. Check for negating adverbs (RB) against defined array('not', 'never')
2. When there's a match, remove the adverb
3. concatenate "not-" to the beginning of every subsequent adjective (JJ), adverb (RB), or verb (VB or VBN for past tense)
4. Remove all POS-tags (/XX)

Thus, the desired output would be:

```
It was not-okay or not-funny and I will not-buy from them not-ever not-again
```

My first thought was to do this the way I know how to: explode the string on space, then explode every word on "/" to [JJ => okay], then make a switch statement to treat every word (case JJ: concatenate, etc.), but this seems very sloppy. Does anybody have a more clean and / or efficient way of doing this, for instance regex? The strings have been pre-cleaned, so they will always only contain words (no punctuation, other characters than a-z, etc.).

*Edit: I am aware, btw, of the very basic character of this way of treating negations, but it is good enough for what I need. There will be an error margin, but that's ok :)*

Comment: How would a regex be cleaner, if this can be solved by one at all? Most likely, it would just make the code cryptic.

Comment: Well, for instance it is perhaps cleaner to have a few short regex to (1) just look for /JJ, /RB, /VB and /VBN and concatenate "not-" in front of it (2) remove all POS-tags. This would be fairly easy I guess for somebody who has good knowledge of regex (which I have not, hence the question :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let me try. Following your question about processing using regex,

```
$s = "It/PRP was/VBD not/RB okay/JJ or/CC funny/JJ and/CC I/NN will/MD 
      never/RB buy/VB from/IN them/PRP ever/RB again/RB";
```

1. Check for negating adverbs (RB) against defined array('not', 'never')
2. When there's a match, remove the adverb

   On other words, remove any "not" and "never" followed by "/RB".

   ```
   $s = preg_replace("/(not|never)\/RB/i", "", $s);
   ```
3. Concatenate "not-" to the beginning of every subsequent adjective (JJ), adverb (RB), or verb (VB or VBN for past tense)

   ```
   $s = preg_replace("/(\w+)\/(JJ|RB|VB|VBN)/", "not-$1/$2", $s);
   ```
4. Remove all POS-tags (/XX)

   Assuming the POS-tags are all uppercase

   ```
   $s = preg_replace("/\/[A-Z]+/", "", $s);
   ```
5. (My additional step). Remove any double spaces from the result of above regexes.

   ```
   $s = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $s);
   ```

The output is:

```
It not-was not-okay or not-funny and I will not-buy from them not-ever not-again
```

If you want to negate another POS-tags other than JJ/RB/VB/VBN, just modify the regex on step 3 (JJ|RB|VB|VBN). Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks! I will have a look at it tomorrow (really need to catch those 6hrs of sleep now while I still can)!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a non-regex solution, as a regex or non-regex method will need to make multiple functions calls.  If there is a way to perform this task with a simple `preg_replace_callback()`, I can only imagine that it would be very difficult to comprehend at first glance.  My approach may be very similar to your original code (but I don't know because you didn't post yours).

Method: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0da1fdbe1a5d74330b5937c240298d294116585f))

```
$string='It/PRP was/VBD not/RB okay/JJ or/CC funny/JJ and/CC I/NN will/MD never/RB buy/VB from/IN them/PRP ever/RB again/RB';

$mods=['JJ','RB','VB','VBN'];  // okay to prefix when called for
$omits=['not','never'];  // strings to be omitted every time
$negbool=false;  // states whether a negative adverb has been found
$array=explode(' ',$string);
foreach($array as $k=>&$v){  // make $v modifiable by reference
    $parts=explode('/',$v);
    // add prefix "not-" to strings who qualify
    if($negbool && in_array($parts[1],$mods) && !in_array($parts[0],$omits)){
        $v="not-{$parts[0]}";
    // omit RB strings that don't qualify for prefixing
    }elseif($parts[1]=='RB'){
        unset($array[$k]);  // remove
        $negbool=true;  // declare that modifiable strings should be modified from this point forward
    // keep only leading substring
    }else{
        $v=$parts[0];
    }
}
echo implode(' ',$array); // glue back together again using spaces
```

Output:

```
It was not-okay or not-funny and I will not-buy from them not-ever not-again
```